# Reversing endianness with memcpy

Tags: iphone, ios, endianness

I'm writing a method that creates an in-memory WAV file.  The first 4 bytes of the file should contain the characters 'RIFF', so I'm writing the bytes like this:

```
Byte *bytes = (Byte *)malloc(len); // overall length of file
char *RIFF = (char *)'RIFF';
memcpy(&bytes[0], &RIFF, 4);
```

The problem is that this writes the first 4 bytes as 'FFIR', thanks to little-endianness.  To correct this problem, I'm just doing this:

```
Byte *bytes = (Byte *)malloc(len); 
char *RIFF = (char *)'FFIR';
memcpy(&bytes[0], &RIFF, 4);
```

This works, but is there a better-looking way of getting `memcpy` to reverse the order of the bytes it's writing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing some bad things with pointers (and some weird but not wrong things).  Try this:

```
Byte *bytes = malloc(len); // overall length of file
char *RIFF = "RIFF";
memcpy(bytes, RIFF, 4);
```

It'll work fine.

Comment: +1, there are 2 problems, one is the line `char *RIFF = (char *)'RIFF';` which instead of assigning the address of 'RIFF' to the pointer, is directly assigning 'RIFF' as the **value** of the pointer. The second (which is why you are getting 'FFIR' and not gibberish or a crash) is the line `memcpy(&bytes[0], &RIFF, 4);` where you are passing the address of the pointer instead of the pointer itself.

Comment: I'm using `&bytes[0]` instead of `bytes` here because I have to do similar writes at other positions in the byte array besides the beginning. I assume this is what you meant by "weird but not wrong".

Comment: @MusiGenesis - that and casting the result of the `malloc()` call.  Argubly casting that result *is* wrong, though.  It's certainly unnecessary.

Comment: it works with or without the cast. I assume malloc returns a byte pointer anyway, so the cast is certainly unnecessary, but why would it be *wrong*?

Comment: @MusiGenesis - it can hide `#include` errors.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc